# HTML entities / special characters in form label tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, special-characters, html-entities

```
<%= f.label :recipient_email, "Friend&rsquo;s email address" %>
```

`&rsquo;` doesn't show up as the actual character. What's the correct way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<%= f.label :recipient_email, raw("Friend&rsquo;s email address") %>
```